# How can I prevent Armory from getting stuck at "30 seconds" Building Databases on OSX 10.9?

Tags: mac, armory

I'm running Bitcoin-Qt v0.8.6-beta and Armory 0.90-beta on OSX 10.9. I've been stuck at "30 seconds" for several hours. This has happened twice now. Activity monitor displays no disk activity, but ~90-120% cpu usage. Bitcoin-Qt is fully synced and displays a green checkmark.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT:**
The log file contains a bunch of messages similar to this:

> -ERROR - 1394339952: (leveldb_wrapper.cpp:1145) Block height exceeds DupID lookup table
>   -ERROR - 1394339952: (leveldb_wrapper.cpp:1145) Block height exceeds DupID lookup table
>   -WARN  - 1394339952: (BlockUtils.cpp:4617)    Tx: d5fdcc541e25de1c
>   -ERROR - 1394339952: (leveldb_wrapper.cpp:1145) Block height exceeds DupID lookup table
>   -ERROR - 1394339952: (leveldb_wrapper.cpp:1145) Block height exceeds DupID lookup table
>   -WARN  - 1394339952: (BlockUtils.cpp:4617)    Tx: 982051fd1e4ba744

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

**WARNING: Triple-check you have a backup of all of your Bitcoin-Qt and Armory wallets before deleting anything.**

Deleting the Armory and Bitcoin data directories (`~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin` and `~/Library/Application Support/Armory`) and re-downloading the entire blockchain (starting with a fresh bootstrap.dat) in Bitcoin-Qt fixed this for me.